# Error: the entity type 'Task' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

This error is occurring whenever I run the `Add-Migration 'init'` command. I have tried every fix imaginable but nothing is working. If anyone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code - `Task` model class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace FNSHR.Models
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Deadline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace FNSHR.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public AppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration) //sets up class before methods can be used
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString"));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried everything I could imagine - it's supposed to just say "Build successful" and create an auto generated file.

Comment: Tried not using the name Task? It is a language keyword.

Comment: Let me give that a shot

Comment: yes Task is a langauage keyword that simply holds the refrence to asychronous operations basically saying the async operation will be completed in future. Changing the name of the class should work just fine. If that does not work try using `[Key] `attribute above the `Id` property.

Comment: Even though it may be fine in your code the analyzers look at your code and generate more code using your variable/type names etc.

Comment: @BrianParker `Task` is not a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/). It is merely the name of a class from a library. It is no different in this regard than `StringBuilder`, `SqlConnection` or `SomeClass`.

Comment: @Sumanjha `Task` is not a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/). It is merely the name of a class from a library. It is no different in this regard than `StringBuilder`, `SqlConnection` or `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Task` class is `FNSHR.Models.Task`.
Your `DbContext` is in a different namespace, `FNSHR.Data`, and you are not `using FNSHR.Models;` there. So your `DbSet<Task>` resolves to `DbSet<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>`.

Make it `DbSet<FNSHR.Models.Task>`.